# cURL file name with special characters PHP

Tags: php, curl, file-upload, special-characters

i am trying to curl file it's name contains special characters

```
curl_setopt($curl_array[$i], CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($curl_array[$i], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl_array[$i], CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS,10);
curl_setopt($curl_array[$i], CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,3600);
curl_setopt($curl_array[$i], CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($curl_array[$i], CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$login:$password");
curl_setopt($curl_array[$i], CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    "cache-control: no-cache","content-type: multipart/form-data",
));
curl_setopt($curl_array[$i], CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl_array[$i], CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl_array[$i], CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,3);
curl_setopt($curl_array[$i], CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $apiData);
```

This works with any file except files contains special characters in their names 
like

`'file' =>'@/path-to-file/5@special!#$%^&_ = - Copy.txt'`